# Smooth Vertex doesn't work

Tags: vertices, vertex-groups

I am new to Blender. I have an object with some edge loops and a mirror modifier, and when I try to Smooth Vertex the vertices of the object, the object split in two. Any ideas ?
[image: Object before Smooth Vertex]

[image: Object after Smooth Vertex]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by enabling "Merge" and increasing the Merge Limit to ~.34. I tested using the dimensions of the default cube.

[image: Merged]

Comment: Thanks ! I forgot to do at least three edge loops and that's why it spilts in two !